# specific search in database

Tags: mysql

I am looking for the method of searching specific words in the mysql with innodb engine. Consider the following example:

```
Text:
1.Card has two sides.
2.This is my card.
3.We have a car.
4.Car has good color.
5.This was my car.
6.The car is nice.
```

Suppose that these points are different rows and lie under same column "Text". I need a query that extract the rows with exactly the word "car" using "like", regardless whether the word "car" is at the begining, at the middle or at the end. Keep in mind the "card" is not required.

Comment: SELECT Text FROM Table WHERE Text LIKE '%Car%';

Comment: @BojanKovacevic it will include `CARD`.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic wouldn't that include 'Card'? I am not 100% sure if OP wants to exclude card by saying "Card is not required" though. Maybe OP can elaborate?

Comment: yes,i dont get that required.

Comment: You could use a regular expression, or perhaps use `LIKE` to check the four combinations of being preceded by dot or space before the text, or having a dot or space after the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here it is..

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '% car' or name LIKE 'car %' or name LIKE '% car %' or name like '% car.';
```

it will select both start word last word and the between word

Answer (score 1):

Use it

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%car' or name LIKE '%car %';
```

Comment: That would not include line #4 example, would it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include "car" and exclude "card" you can search for

```
SELECT Text FROM Table WHERE Text LIKE '% Car.%' or Text LIKE '% Car %';
```

That would require there to be always a "." in the end.
You can add another

```
or Text LIKE '% Car';
```

if you are not sure about this.

If this gets more complicated, you might want to look into regular expressions though. While often slower, they will be faster if your LIKE... OR... expression gets too complicated. You might have to do some benchmarking to find out which is best in your situation.